# yt-dlp Permission denied error

Tags: command-line, permissions, youtube, youtube-dl

Because of slow speed on `youtube-dl` and after reading   [this discussion](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/30102) I am trying to use `yt-dlp` (current version : 2021.12.27).
But when I run `yt-dlp https://youtu.be/qIX1BhvUMJ0` I am getting error. Error is given below :

> ```
> [youtube] qIX1BhvUMJ0: Downloading webpage
> [youtube] qIX1BhvUMJ0: Downloading android player API JSON
> [info] qIX1BhvUMJ0: Downloading 1 format(s): 18
> [download] Got file access error. Retrying (attempt 1 of 10) ...
> [download] Got file access error. Retrying (attempt 2 of 10) ...
> [download] Got file access error. Retrying (attempt 3 of 10) ...
> [download] Got file access error. Retrying (attempt 4 of 10) ...
> [download] Got file access error. Retrying (attempt 5 of 10) ...
> [download] Got file access error. Retrying (attempt 6 of 10) ...
> [download] Got file access error. Retrying (attempt 7 of 10) ...
> [download] Got file access error. Retrying (attempt 8 of 10) ...
> [download] Got file access error. Retrying (attempt 9 of 10) ...
> [download] Got file access error. Retrying (attempt 10 of 10) ...
> ERROR: unable to open for writing: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '12 seconds later [qIX1BhvUMJ0].mp4.part'
> ```

I don't know what is this. Please help me.

##### EDIT 1:

How did I install `yt-dlp` => https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#installation
I run `yt-dlp https://youtu.be/qIX1BhvUMJ0` from my home directory `/home/abhishek`

Comment: How did you install it? Which directory are you running these commands in? Edit the post to add this information please

Comment: I have updated my question. Please take a look.

Comment: There are three methods in the link.

Answer (score 2):

Use the -P option of yt-dlp to specify a path to write the files into, and make sure the current user has write permission on this path.

```
yt-dlp -P /home/example https://youtu.be/zzzzz
```

The issue might also be because you have install a snap of yt-dlp, which will then try to save the files into a folder structure within the snap install. If this is the problem you might have better luck removing the snap and installing via pip.

Comment: Okay, let me check with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to mention for others that may use youtube-dl-material,

I got this error

```
ERROR: unable to create directory [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

because of using a slash ( / ) at the beginning of my directory path. It's a relative path and wasn't thinking about it right for like 2 weeks now and finally figured out. Just remove the starting / from my directory,

instead of

```
"/home/videos"
```

it'd be

```
"home/videos"
```